# A function is being called from a module, before the module was imported

Tags: python, python-import

I was looking at a [code golf solution,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207475) and the code for it was(written by TFeld):

```
lambda s:all(''.join(p)in s for p in permutations({*s}))
from itertools import*
```

How is this possible?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: the library is probably imported in your environment before

Comment: Because the function `s` doesn't get called before the import (nor indeed at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, the import should go first.

The usual standards for the PPCG site allow answers to create a function that satisfies the challenge requirements, without actually saving it anywhere. At the time the `lambda` creates the function, `permutations` is not available, but the function is not executed, so no error occurs. If the function created by the `lambda` were to be executed at the end of this code block, `permutations` would be available at that point, so no error would occur.

However, the function created by the `lambda` does not survive to the point after the `import`. At no point in this code's execution is there actually a function that satisfies the challenge's requirements. The function's dependencies aren't available until after the function's lifetime ends.

Switching the lambda and the import would resolve this issue without requiring extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

That code is a no-op. It defines a lambda which is never executed, so Python never encounters the NameError.

Actually executing the lambda before importing `itertools` would reveal the error.